# How to solve this in modeling data, prediction data in r code

Tags: r, data-modeling

```
error : Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
0 (non-NA) cases
```

The included coding was previously used to analyze air pollutant data and build a regression model to predict air pollution standard index (ISPU) categories based on air pollutant parameters such as PM10, PM2.5, SO2, CO, O3, and NO2.

Here's a brief explanation for each section of coding:

Modeling function
The modeling function is used to build a regression model based on the selected model type. Available model types include:

Linear Regression
Quadratic Regression
Cubic Regression
Logarithmic Regression
Prediction function
The prediction function is used to make predictions using the regression model that has been built. This function accepts the model, the number of predictions (pnjgpred), and data as input, and returns a dataframe of the predicted results.

Graphic function
The graph function is used to create graphs of prediction results. This graph compares the prediction results with the original data and the regression that has been built.

How to solve this problem, please
code :
I've tried adding na.action=na.exclude in regres

When I ran the program in the safe modeling function section, then it was also predicted to be safe, an error occurred when using the modeling function, using the logarithmic regression type, a `Warning: NAs introduced by coercionError in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular) appeared. ok = single.ok, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'.` Apart from that, the data ispu_clean is not found `also appeared`

```
ispu <- vroom(here("data-ISPU.csv"))
ispu

ispu_clean <- ispu %>% mutate_at(vars(-tanggal), ~ifelse(. == "---", NA, .)) %>% drop_na()
ispu_clean
```

```
# pengonversian variabel categori menjadi numerik
ispu_clean$pm10 <- as.numeric(ispu_clean$pm10)
ispu_clean$pm25 <- as.numeric(ispu_clean$pm25)
ispu_clean$so2 <- as.numeric(ispu_clean$so2)
ispu_clean$co <- as.numeric(ispu_clean$co)
ispu_clean$o3 <- as.numeric(ispu_clean$o3)
ispu_clean$no2 <- as.numeric(ispu_clean$no2)

ispu_clean$categori_numeric <- ifelse(ispu_clean$categori == "baik", 1,
                                     ifelse(ispu_clean$categori == "sedang", 2,
                                            ifelse(ispu_clean$categori == "tidak sehat", 3, NA)))

# Menampilkan hasil
print(ispu_clean)

# Fungsi untuk membuat model regresi
modeling <- function(jenis, datanya){
  model <- switch (jenis,
    "linier" = lm(categori_numeric ~ pm10 + pm25 + so2 + co + o3 + no2, data = datanya),  # Regresi Linier
    "kuadratik" = lm(categori_numeric ~ poly(pm10, 2, raw = TRUE) + poly(pm25, 2, raw = TRUE) + poly(so2, 2, raw = TRUE) + poly(co, 2, raw = TRUE) + poly(o3, 2, raw = TRUE) + poly(no2, 2, raw = TRUE), data = datanya),  # Regresi Kuadratik
    "kubik" =  lm(categori_numeric ~ poly(pm10, 3, raw = TRUE) + poly(pm25, 3, raw = TRUE) + poly(so2, 3, raw = TRUE) + poly(co, 3, raw = TRUE) + poly(o3, 3, raw = TRUE) + poly(no2, 3, raw = TRUE), data = datanya),    # Regresi Kubik
    "logaritmik" = lm(categori_numeric ~ log(pm10) + log(pm25) + log(so2) + log(co) + log(o3) + log(no2), data = datanya)  # Regresi Logaritmik
  )
  return(model)
}

# Fungsi untuk melakukan prediksi
prediksinya <- function(model, pnjgpred, datanya){
  nr <- nrow(datanya)
  
  # Membuat data frame baru untuk prediksi
  newdata <- data.frame(
    pm10 = rep(mean(datanya$pm10), pnjgpred),  
    pm25 = rep(mean(datanya$pm25), pnjgpred),  
    so2 = rep(mean(datanya$so2), pnjgpred),    
    co = rep(mean(datanya$co), pnjgpred),      
    o3 = rep(mean(datanya$o3), pnjgpred),      
    no2 = rep(mean(datanya$no2), pnjgpred)     
  )
  
  # Prediksi dengan model regresi
  prediksi <- predict(model, newdata = newdata, interval = "confidence")
  
  # Membuat data frame untuk hasil prediksi
  pdpred <- data.frame(prediksi)
  pdpred <- pdpred %>%
    mutate(index = seq(nr + 1, nr + pnjgpred), .before = fit)
  
  return(pdpred)
}

# Fungsi untuk membuat grafik
grafik <- function(model, pdpred, datanya){
  colors <- c("Regresi" = "blue", "Data Asli" = "black", "Prediksi" = "red", "Batas Bawah" = "orange", "Batas Atas" = "green")
  
  ggplot() + 
    geom_line(data = datanya, aes(x=index, y=predict(model), color = "Regresi") ) +
    geom_point(data = datanya, aes(x=index, y=categori_numeric, color = "Data Asli")) +
    geom_line(data = datanya, aes(x=index, y=categori_numeric, color = "Data Asli")) +
    geom_point(data = pdpred, aes(x=index, y=fit, color="Prediksi")) +
    geom_point(data = pdpred, aes(x=index, y=lwr, color="Batas Bawah")) +
    geom_point(data = pdpred, aes(x=index, y=upr, color="Batas Atas")) +
    scale_color_manual(
      name = "Grafik Regresi ISPU",
      values = colors,
      guide = "legend") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
      legend.position = "right"
    ) + 
    labs(x = "Index",
         y = "Kategori ISPU")
}

# Contoh penggunaan
model <- modeling("logaritmik", ispu_clean)
df <- prediksinya(model, 12, ispu_clean)
grafik(model, df, ispu_clean)
```